# Android: RecyclerLayout is adding default padding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm trying to create a Collapsing Toolbar Layout using RecyclerLayout.

The problem is that, When I'm inflating the Layout during run time, it's adding a default padding on it's own.

Below are my layout xmls:

`activity_profile.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recycler"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="180dp"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

       <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
           android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
           app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/header"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
               app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

       </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
       app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried to remove `activity_horizontal_margin` as well but it does not seem to work.

Here is the layout that I'm trying to inflate in the `recycler-layout`:

`profile_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorProfileStatsBackground"      
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image: Final Output]

Comment: Add screen shots of current output and expected output for better understanding

Comment: try removing this `android:paddingStart="-20dp"`

Comment: @VishvaDave : Yup, have added now

Comment: @SantanuSur : Removed it, still the same.

Comment: @AkshaySingh I have tried your code i am not getting any padding https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEgqs.png

Comment: try coordinator layout height `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Comment: @VishvaDave: The screenshot I have is from my device: Google Pixel 2

Comment: @SantanuSur: Sure, will try that

Comment: @AkshaySingh then try on different divice because it is working perfectly for me

Comment: @AkshaySingh add this line in recycleview. you will be able to see in preview as well `tools:listitem="@layout/profile_view"`
       `tools:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"`

Comment: @VishvaDave: My preview is the same as expected, only on device this padding is rendered, which is wierd.

Comment: @SantanuSur: still the same, after doing `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem.

The problem was with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in **AppBarLayout**.

I did some research, and found an article [fitsSystemWindow](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec) which decribes that the default behavior of this attribute is that it **sets the padding** of the View to ensure the contents don’t overlay the system windows.